# Is being positive and orthogonal sufficient for being identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n$x$n$ matrix and $I$ be identity matrix of $n$x$n$. $A$ follows the following two conditions

1. It is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) that is $A^TA=AA^{T}=I$ where $A^T$ stands for transpose of $A$.
2. It is [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix)  that is $v^T A v \ge 0 $ for all $n$ x 1 non-null column vectors ( $v$ ).

**EDIT**
$A$ is symmetric also ( condition 3 ) and the base field is real.

Is it necessary that $A$ is identity ?

Comment: Define "positive". (I think I know what you mean, and in that case the answer is yes, but still.)

Comment: @Ian I modified my question

Comment: An overkill proof: an orthogonal matrix is normal; a normal matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable; an orthogonal matrix has eigenvalues of modulus 1. Now use your positivity condition to test the eigenvalues.

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be symmetric ?

Comment: yes in my case it is. Could you explain why being symmetric is necessary for it to be identity apart from the other 2 conditions ?

Comment: @moderators I included the missing things in EDIT and I am satisfied with the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is NOT necessarily the identity matrix.
For example, when $n=2$ and the base field is $\mathbb{R}$ the rotation matrices
$$A_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\
sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$
are orthogonal and positive if $\theta \in [-\pi / 2, \pi / 2]$.
This example easily generalizes to arbitrary $n$ by considering block diagonal matrices.
Note that these matrices may be diagonalized (over $\mathbb{C}$), but their diagonalizations do not have real entries in general.

Comment: for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ the eigen values are not real how can it be positive am i missing something ?

Comment: @sasha that's correct. The zeros of the characteristic polynomial $det(xI - A_{\pi / 2})$ are not real, but nonetheless $v^tAv \ge 0$ for all $v \ne 0$.

Comment: I get it the base field is real missed that. Thanks alot for clearing my doubt .

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is definite positive, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries such that

$$A=Q^TDQ$$

If $A$ is also orthogonal, then
$$I=A^TA=Q^TD^TDQ\implies I=D^2$$

but $D$ is real and positive, so
$$D=I\implies A=I$$